# Simple calculator in html/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, calculator

I'm trying to make a calculator with html and JavaScript. After clicking on the button i'm trying to insert the number into my div. When i do so the default '0' disappears and it does not insert anything at all.

```js
    function copy(event) {
        var newValue = event.target.value;
        document.querySelector("#display").innerHTML = newValue;
    }

    var textfield = document.querySelector("#btn_7");
    textfield.addEventListener("click", copy);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="frame">
  <div id="display">0</div>
  <button id="btn_7">7</button>
  <button id="btn_8">8</button>
  <button id="btn_9">9</button>
  <button id="btn_div">/</button>
  <button id="btn_4">4</button>
  <button id="btn_5">5</button>
  <button id="btn_6">6</button>
  <button id="btn_prod">*</button>
  <button id="btn_1">1</button>
  <button id="btn_2">2</button>
  <button id="btn_3">3</button>
  <button id="btn_min">-</button>
  <button id="btn_clear">C</button>
  <button id="btn_0">0</button>
  <button id="btn_eq">=</button>
  <button id="btn_plus">+</button>
</div>
```

If I add a string to newValue variable it shows in my div. So it means like when I press on the button it doesnt give anything to the div. Is there a way to solve this?

And about `var textfield = document.querySelector("#btn_7");`

For now I have to make this for each button and thats will take a lot of rows is there a better way to do so?

Comment: Actually, you can just replace `textfield.addEventListener("click", copy);` by `document.querySelector("#frame").addEventListener("click", copy);`, since `event.target` already takes care of event delegation. You might want to check something like `if(event.target.matches("button"))`, though.

Answer (score 1):

Buttons don't have a default attribute `value`, so in this case use the attribute `textContent`.

I recommend you to use a hidden input to store the values or you can also use `data-attributes`.

> For now i have to make this for each button and that will take alot of rows is there a better way to do so?

You can use the function `document.querySelectorAll(selector)` and loop over it to bind the specific event.

```js
function copy(event) {
  var newValue = event.target.textContent;
  document.querySelector("#display").innerHTML = newValue;
}

Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('button'), function(b) {
  b.addEventListener("click", copy);
});
```

```html
<div id="frame">
  <div id="display">0</div>
  <button id="btn_7">7</button>
  <button id="btn_8">8</button>
  <button id="btn_9">9</button>
  <button id="btn_div">/</button>
  <button id="btn_4">4</button>
  <button id="btn_5">5</button>
  <button id="btn_6">6</button>
  <button id="btn_prod">*</button>
  <button id="btn_1">1</button>
  <button id="btn_2">2</button>
  <button id="btn_3">3</button>
  <button id="btn_min">-</button>
  <button id="btn_clear">C</button>
  <button id="btn_0">0</button>
  <button id="btn_eq">=</button>
  <button id="btn_plus">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```js
$(function(){
 
 $('button[id^="btn_"]').click(function(){
  var display;
  if($('.tmp').length > 0){
   display = $('.tmp').text();
  }else{
   $( "<p class='tmp' style='display:none;'></p>" ).appendTo( "#frame" );
   display = '';
  }
  switch($(this).text()){
   case 'C' :
    display = '0';
   break;
   case '=' :
    display = eval(display);
   break;
   default :
    display = display.concat($(this).text());
  }
  $('#display').text(display);
  $('.tmp').text((display != '0') ? display : '');
 });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="frame">
 <div id="display">0</div>
 <button id="btn_7">7</button>
 <button id="btn_8">8</button>
 <button id="btn_9">9</button>
 <button id="btn_div">/</button><br/>
 <button id="btn_4">4</button>
 <button id="btn_5">5</button>
 <button id="btn_6">6</button>
 <button id="btn_prod">*</button><br/>
 <button id="btn_1">1</button>
 <button id="btn_2">2</button>
 <button id="btn_3">3</button>
 <button id="btn_min">-</button><br/>
 <button id="btn_clear">C</button>
 <button id="btn_0">0</button>
 <button id="btn_eq">=</button>
 <button id="btn_plus">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution

Answer (score -1):

Here is to select value and replace html of display div. You need to do some extra stuff to achieve what is your desired output.

```js
var display = $('#display');
$('.btn').click(function(e) {
  var btn = e.target;
  display.html(btn.id);
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="frame">
<div id="display">0</div>
<button class="btn" id="btn_7">7</button>
<button class="btn"  id="btn_8">8</button>
<button class="btn"  id="btn_9">9</button>
<button class="btn"  id="btn_div">/</button>
<button class="btn"  id="btn_4">4</button>
<button class="btn"  id="btn_5">5</button>
<button class="btn"  id="btn_6">6</button>
<button class="btn"  id="btn_prod">*</button>
<button class="btn"  id="btn_1">1</button>
<button class="btn"  id="btn_2">2</button>
<button class="btn"  id="btn_3">3</button>
<button class="btn"  id="btn_min">-</button>
<button class="btn"  id="btn_clear">C</button>
<button class="btn"  id="btn_0">0</button>
<button class="btn"  id="btn_eq">=</button>
<button class="btn"  id="btn_plus">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Why even add classes? Just use `$("#display").on("click", "button", function(e){`…`});`. Also, the ID isn’t supposed to be added; the inner text is.

Comment: Just to distinguish which buttons needs that click handler. Maybe OP does not want to do the same for some other buttons.